# calendar_for in ruby on rails (table_builder)

Tags: ruby

Hi im trying to display a list of films that are showing on a participial date using table_builder this is the code in the view.

```
<%= calendar_for @showings, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month do |calendar| %>
<%= calendar.head('Sun','Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat') %>
<%= calendar.day(:day_method => :date) do |date, showings| %>
<%= date.day %>
<ul>
<% for showing in showings %>
<%= link_to h(showing.film.title),showing%>
</br>
<% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

the code works however if a film is screening multiple times on the same day then the film title is also printed out multiple times on the calendar under the same date. What i want really is to find out if a film already has a screening on a particular day, if so then only show the title of that film once. Any ideas how i might go about doing that.

code in showing controller

```
def whats_on
@showings = Showing.all
@date = params[:month] ? Date.strptime(params[:month]) : Date.today
end
```

current relationship

```
film - has_many :showings
showing - belongs_to :film
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
 <% showings.group_by{|s| s.film.title}.each do |title, shows %>
    <%= link_to h(title), some_path %>
    <% shows.each do |s| %>
      <%= link_to s.something,s%>
    <% end %>
    </br>
 <% end %>

 def whats_on
   @showings = Showing.all(:include => :film)
   @date = params[:month] ? Date.strptime(params[:month]) : Date.today
 end
```

Comment: hmmm now it doesn't like the :date attribute defined for showing. undefined method `date' for #<Array:0x3ad2560> on line 11             <%= calendar.day(:day_method => :date) do |date, showings| %>

Comment: Otherwise you can use `group_by` in view (i.e.) `showings.all(:include => :film).group_by{|s| s.film.title}`.

Comment: sorry i'm kinda confused                                         <ul>
   <% for showing in showings %>
   <%= link_to h(@showings(:include => :film)).group_by{|s| s.film.title},showing.film%>
   </br>
   <% end %>
   </ul>                                              something like this?

Comment: hmm undefined method `all' for []:Array

Comment: eager loading you can do it in controller.

Comment: `<ul> <% for showing in showings %> <%= link_to h(@showings(:include => :film)).group_by{|s| s.film.title},showing.film%> </br> <% end %> </ul>` this makes no sense to me. your `showings` and `@showings` are same, right?

Comment: yes showings and @showings are the same thing, i've tried the code above and it sorts the films by their title. I rather it only show one instance of a film if they occur on the same day however now that it sorts films by their order i think it'll be better to also show the time next to them. So even if 'the hobbit' is displayed twice the time next to the title will be different, a film has a showing and the showing has a start_time, i've got the time displaying next to each film <% showings.group_by{|s| s.start_time} %> however its in random order any ideas on how to display it ascending?

Comment: you want to order complete showings on start_time or title-wise ordering on start_time ?

Comment: what i would like is for e.g. the hobbit: 10:30, the hobbit 16:00, the hobbit 19:30 in that order currently they are in random order...the hobbit 19:30, the hobbit 16:00, the hobbit 10:30. i tried using .asctime however apprantly the start_time attribute for showings is printed out as a string even though in the table it is of type .time

Comment: Try this: `@showings = Showing.order('start_time DESC').all(:include => :film)`

Comment: it sorting them out in some order but in not quite why its displaying like this so if i use the code above i the controller i get ... hobbit 16:00, hobbit 10:30, hobbit 19:30, iron man 3 19:00 and if i use ASC instead it prints hobbit 19:30, hobbit 10:30, hobbit 16:00, iron man 3 19:00.

Comment: ok i think it works, its not sorting the times that already exist however if you create new times for a film then its sorting them out just fine.